# Second nginx auth_request timed out

Tags: nginx

I have the following nginx setup:

```
    location = /novnc-auth {
        internal;
        # calls the django view below
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/proxmox/novnc-connection-lookup/$cookie_novnc/;
        # set $pve $upstream_http_pve;
        # set $vmhhost $upstream_http_vmhhost;
    }

    location = /novnc/ {
        auth_request /novnc-auth;
        auth_request_set $vmhhost $upstream_http_vmhhost;
        auth_request_set $pve $upstream_http_pve;
        proxy_set_header Cookie 'PVEAuthCookie=$pve';
        proxy_pass https://$vmhhost;
    }
    
    location ~ /vncproxy/ {
        auth_request /novnc-auth;
        auth_request_set $vmhhost $upstream_http_vmhhost;
        auth_request_set $pve $upstream_http_pve;
        proxy_set_header Cookie 'PVEAuthCookie=$pve';
        proxy_pass https://$vmhhost;
    }
```

django view

```py
   def view(self, ...):
        data = json.loads(data_string)
        resp = HttpResponse(data_string)
        resp['Pve'] = data['pve']
        resp['Vmhhost'] = data['host']
        return resp
```

A popup html window opens at `/novnc/`, which subsequently fires an ajax call to `/vncproxy/`.

The problem I am having is, first call to `/novnc/` worked as it should, performs `auth_request` fine, but then when an ajax call to `/vncproxy/` it hangs on the `auth_request` part and giving me `upstream timed out (110: Connection timed out) while reading response header from upstream` then `auth request unexpected status: 504 while sending to client, client`

[image]

Comment: Can you explain more why you are firing the `auth_request` two times?

Comment: Because of 2 separate requests

Comment: @JamesLin Why are you using `auth_request_set` twice in `location = /novnc/ { ... }` and `location ~ /vncproxy/ { ... }` blocks instead of using them once in `location = /novnc-auth { ... }` block?

Comment: @IvanShatsky because that second request is triggered by the html from the first proxy

Comment: @JamesLin From the nginx point of view those requests are independent, each one processed by its own worker and nginx variables doesn't interfere between different requests. You can safely simplify your config moving `auth_request_set` directives to the `location = /novnc-auth { ... }` block.

Comment: Ok thanks I will give that a try tomorrow, I am not good at nginx, I was under the impression that `auth_request_set` can only be used at the same context as `auth_request`

Answer (score 0):

I digged into it and have build a Poc that had a similiar problem till I removed the `not_modified` headers

```
    if_modified_since off;
    add_header Last-Modified "";
```

in my `auth_request` backend mock `http://127.0.0.1:8080/;`. This mocks your auth-app running on port `8000`.

```
server {
  listen 80;

    location = /novnc-auth {
        internal;
        # calls the django view below
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8080/;
        set $pve $upstream_http_pve;
        set $vmhhost $upstream_http_vmhhost;
    }

    location = /novnc/ {
        auth_request /novnc-auth;
        auth_request_set $vmhhost $upstream_http_vmhhost;
        proxy_pass http://$vmhhost;
    }

    location ~ /vncproxy/ {
        auth_request /novnc-auth;
        auth_request_set $pvmhhost $upstream_http_vmhhost;
        proxy_pass http://$pvmhhost;
    }

}

server {
  listen 9000;

  location / {
   root /usr/share/nginx/html;
   index index.html;
  }
}

server {
  listen 8080;

  location / {
    root /usr/share/nginx/html;
    index index.html;
    if_modified_since off;
    add_header Last-Modified "";
    add_header "vmhhost" "127.0.0.1:9000/";
    add_header "pve" "Somedata";
  }
}
```

My index.html file loaded includes an XHR-Request that will triggered as soon as I load the page.

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Welcome to nginx!</title>
<style>
    body {
        width: 35em;
        margin: 0 auto;
        font-family: Tahoma, Verdana, Arial, sans-serif;
    }
</style>
</head>
<body>
    <script type="text/javascript">

var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
       // Typical action to be performed when the document is ready:
       document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = xhttp.responseText;
    }
};
xhttp.open("GET", "http://localhost:55000/vncproxy/", true);
xhttp.send();

    </script>

    <div id="demo"></div>
<h1>Welcome to nginx!</h1>
<p>If you see this page, the nginx web server is successfully installed and
working. Further configuration is required.</p>

<p>For online documentation and support please refer to
<a href="http://nginx.org/">nginx.org</a>.<br/>
Commercial support is available at
<a href="http://nginx.com/">nginx.com</a>.</p>

<p><em>Thank you for using nginx.</em></p>
</body>
</html>
```

The debug-log of NGINX is showing that the `auth_request` was triggered twice and called successfully.

Your error says it can connect to the upstream but failed to receive the http header. Are you able to share the debug logs from that request? Another test you can try is to use some fake auth server like I did and see if that is working with your JavaScript Frontend to determine where the problem sits.

Comment: Thanks for trying to help, so did you get similar problem with the `modified headers` or without?

Comment: With. Yes if the AJAX call is a POST your configuration looks legit. Great to hear it is working now.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out by following the [example](https://docs.nginx.com/nginx/admin-guide/security-controls/configuring-subrequest-authentication/), the problem is that I needed to set the following, I just realised ajax call was making a POST method

```
location = /novnc-auth {
        internal;
        # calls the django view below
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8080/;
        proxy_pass_request_body off;
        proxy_set_header Content-Length "";
        proxy_set_header X-Original-URI $request_uri;
    }
```